# How to block wind by terrain in Unity with wind zone?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to add wind effect in my homework of game development with Unity. I use the [wind zone compoenent](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/terrain-WindZones.html) provided by Unity. However, the wind can not be blocked by terrain.

How to make the wind blocked by terrain?

Answer (score 0):

Add a Terrain Collider Component to your terrain

[Unity Docs for Terrain Collider](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TerrainCollider.html)